# npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"6.0.8" from @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.8 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.8
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@6.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"6.0.7" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.0.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"<7.0.0" from @swimlane/ngx-datatable@13.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable
npm ERR!       @swimlane/ngx-datatable@"^13.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"6.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"<7.0.0" from @swimlane/ngx-datatable@13.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable
npm ERR!     @swimlane/ngx-datatable@"^13.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (ag-grid-angular, codelyzer, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"6.0.8" from @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@">=2.1.x" from ag-grid-angular@18.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/ag-grid-angular
npm ERR!     ag-grid-angular@"^18.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"6.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@6.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"6.0.8" from @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@">=2.1.x" from ag-grid-angular@18.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/ag-grid-angular
npm ERR!       ag-grid-angular@"^18.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"6.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

trying to run a project